# Git push without merge, or reverse fetch

Tags: git

I want to sync some configuration files between two computers, computer A and computer B. computer A has an ssh login on computer B, but not the other way around.

When I have ssh connections both ways I usually do this: run fetch, and then merge remote/upstream/master, from either repo. That way I can let things diverge and only have to merge when I have the time.

When I only have a one way connection I can get changes from B to A as usual by running in A: git fetch B, and then git merge remotes/B/master. To get changes from A to B I try to run from A: git push B. But I get error message `error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master`. This is because I'm trying to push to a checked out branch and thus update HEAD (as I understand it). But I don't want to update HEAD, I only want to changes from A available in B as remotes/A/master. So I would like a push option where push from A to B does not try to update B's head or master. Which is the same thing as fetch but in reverse.

Another way of putting it: pull is fetch + merge, and you can split them up. But push is what plus merge?

Comment: push to a different branch `--set-upstream`

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish. It isn't very clear.

Comment: I want to occasionally sync work between two repos when I only have a one way ssh connection.

Comment: Sounds like dropbox

Comment: @Oxymoron [Not as simple as it sounds](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox#faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

(Remember that there are two Gits involved here.  You're calling one *A*.  From machine *A* you can ssh into machine *B*, so on machine *A*, in the repository there, you use the remote name `B` to talk about "the other Git".  Meanwhile on machine *B* you use remote name `A` to talk about "the other Git".)

Use `git push B master:refs/remotes/A/master` to create or update an actual remote-tracking name on `A`.  Use `git push B +master:refs/remotes/A/master` to force-overwrite the remote-tracking name on `A` (or the same with `--force` and without the plus sign).

You can use `git push B master:A/master` to make or update a regular (local branch, not remote-tracking name) `A/master` on `A`.  As before you can add `--force` or a plus sign to this refspec to overwrite.

If you use `remotes/A/master`, without the `refs/` part, this creates a *local* branch named `remotes/A/master`, which I think is a bad idea.  On machine `A`, run `git branch` and `git branch -r` to see the distinction between branch names and remote-tracking names; or use `git for-each-ref` to dump them all out in their full-name forms.

#### Long

First, let's note that `git push` *does not merge*.  Neither does `git fetch`, for that matter.  The *refusing to update* message has nothing to do with merges!  Your diagnosis here is at least partly correct (depending on what you mean by *diverge*—you did not say *from what* ):

> ... fails because it would make worktree and index diverge

In fact, the index and work-tree would *remain unchanged*, and that's the problem.

All you need to do here is `git push` to some name that is *not* the currently-checked-out branch name.

When you run `git push`, you direct your Git to call up another Git, usually via https (port 443) or ssh (port 22) to some IP address.  That other Git *is* a repository, with its own branches.  If it's a `--bare` repository, it has *no* work-tree and no one can be doing any work in it, so it will generally accept pushes.  If *not*, it has a work-tree, indexed by its index, and someone could be doing work in it.

Consider what a commit *is*.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, which is in effect that commit's real, true name.  Each commit stores a *snapshot* of all files, and each commit stores some metadata *about* that snapshot: who made it (name and email address), when (time-stamp), and *why* (log message).  It also stores the hash ID—the true name—of its immediate parent commit, or, for merge commits, all of its parent commits.

Branch names, in a Git repository, serve to locate the *last* commit in a chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

The branch name stores the hash ID of commit `H`.  `H` itself stores the hash ID of its predecessor `G`, which stores another ID `F`, and so on back through history.

When you run `git push`, your Git calls up some other Git.  Your Git then offers their Git some commit hash ID(s).  They either *do* have this commit—hash IDs are universal across *all* Gits, via the magic of cryptographic checksums—or they don't.  If they don't have the commit, they need it (and all of its files) and maybe its parent commit too (and all of *that* commit's files) and maybe the parent's parent, and so on.  Essentially, they need any commits that you have that they don't.  So your Git offers them commits until their Git says: "OK, I have that one and all the earlier ones too, you can stop now."

Then your Git sends those commits (and their files).  That's where you see the counting and compressing and writing objects messages.  Eventually your Git has sent them everything they need.  If they already had the commits, this phase sends no data at all, but no matter what, in the end, they have the commits.

Now your Git does the last part of `git push`: it asks, politely (push without `--force`), or commands (`git push --force`), that the other Git set some of *its* branch name(s) to remember the commit(s) you just sent them, or didn't send them if they already had them.

Let's say you send them new commit `I` whose parent is `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch
            \
             I
```

They now have `I`, but now you ask them: *Set your name `branch` to remember commit `I` instead of `H`, OK?*

That's *not* OK, because someone has `branch` checked out!  For all their Git knows, that someone is busy editing files and fiddling with the index and/or work-tree and plans to make *their own* commit `J` in a nanosecond or two:

```
...--F--G--H--J   <-- branch
            \
             I
```

which would leave `I` all weirded out, or:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch
```

which, because `git push` *doesn't* do any merging, would make commit `J` effectively *undo* commit `I`.

So their Git (which is really yours, you're just standing on the wrong side of the Internet while you do this) says *No, you can't make **my** name `branch` remember commit `J`, it's busy remembering commit `H` while my user works!*

But you *can* ask them to set, say, `merge-me-into-branch`, a name that doesn't exist right now.  For their Git, that's a *new* name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch
            \
             I   <-- merge-me-into-branch
```

So all you need to do is run:

```
git push <remote-or-URL> branch:merge-me-into-branch
```

to create *new* name `merge-me-into-branch` in "their" Git to remember new commit `I`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. After reading it I figured I could do what I want with git push B master:remotes/A/master which worked, even with master checked out in B. Add this to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Also isn't moving a branch to point to a new later commit a kind of merge, a fast forward merge? It still seems to me like git push does do merge.

Comment: Git does sometimes call that a *fast-forward merge*, but a fast-forward merge isn't a merge. It's just a fast-forward. Git calls it a fast-forward ªoperation*, without using the word "merge", when you use `git fetch` or `git push` to cause it to happen. It only calls it a fast-forward merge when you use the `git merge` command to cause it to happen. Note, by the way, that using `remotes/A/master` just creates a *branch* named `remotes/A/master`—you'd have to use `refs/remotes/A/master` to create a remote-tracking name. (Use `git branch -r` or `git branch -a` to see this.)

Comment: You're right, I got confused because I already had a remote branch setup and then it is ok to push with `remotes/A/master` but you might as well use `A/master`

Answer (score 1):

***tl;dr*** You need a 3rd bare repository for repoA and repoB (and repoC and repoD...) to coordinate with. Any Git service will provide you with one. Or you can use computer B since you can login to it. Or you can stick the common repository on Dropbox, [though that's not as simple as it sounds](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox).

---

You're swimming upstream against two problems. First, as you've discovered, you can't push to a branch that's checked out. If you could it would lead to much confusion. A checked out branch implies somebody might be actively working on it or using it. While someone is working on the checkout `HEAD` would move out from beneath them and their working copy would be out of sync.

Try to bring them into sync and they'll get another big surprise as suddenly their working copy changes. For example, let's say you left some edits on B and then tried to push from A to B. What should Git do?

> *pull is fetch + merge, and you can split them up. But push is what plus merge?*

`push` does not merge, it will only fast forward. `push` is basically a `fetch` in reverse, it sends the missing objects. But then it will *only* fast forward.

Let's say you did some work on repoA and pushed.

```
repoA  A - B - C - D - E [master]

repoB  A - B - C [master]
```

repoA will send D and E. And then repoB will slide `master` forward to E. No merge required.

What if you did work on both repoA and repoB?

```
repoA  A - B - C - D - E [master]

repoB  A - B - C - F - G [master]
```

When repoA tries to push Git will notice that the branches have "diverged". Their common ancestor, C, is not at the tip of repoB/master. This requires a merge. Merges often require human intervention, but there's no human on the repoB side. Git doesn't allow it because it makes things even more confusing.

---

Instead, *rebase* your changes on top of B. Then push. This makes you do the work of stitching the two branches together, and because we've rebased instead of merged it will be a simple fast-forward.

Again, starting with our divergent repositories.

```
repoA  A - B - C - D - E [master]

repoB  A - B - C - F - G [master]
```

If `repoA` runs `git pull --rebase` (I recommend setting `pull.rebse = preserve` so `git pull` rebases and preserved branches by default, it results in a much cleaner history than regular merge pulls) then it will fetch F and G.

```
                 F - G [repoB/master]
                /
repoA  A - B - C - D - E [master]

repoB  A - B - C - F - G [master]
```

And then pretend D and E were written on top of G all along.

```
                       D1 - E1 [master]
                      /
                 F - G [repoB/master]
                /
repoA  A - B - C 

repoB  A - B - C - F - G [master]
```

Now when `repoA` (force) pushes to `repoB` it's a simple fast forward.

---

That's the workflow I recommend for any project. However, this doesn't solve the problem of `repoB` being checked out. To solve this you need a 3rd bare repository that they both push and pull to.

```
                 D - E [master]
                /
repoA  A - B - C [common/master]

repoB  A - B - C [common/master]
                \
                 F - G [master]

common A - B - C [master]
```

`repoA` and `repoB` both use `common` as their remote. Both `repoA` and `repoB` push and pull their changes to and from the bare repo `common`. `common` is not checked out. It provides a static location for `repoA` and `repoB` to share their work.

For example, repoA can push to common.

```
                         [common/master]
repoA  A - B - C - D - E [master]

repoB  A - B - C [common/master]
                \
                 F - G [master]

common A - B - C - D - E [master]
```

Then repoB can `git pull --rebase` to get an update from `common` and replay its own changes on top of that.

```
                         [common/master]
repoA  A - B - C - D - E [master]

                                   [common/master]
repoB  A - B - C - D - E - F1 - G1 [master]

common A - B - C - D - E - F1 - G1 [master]
```

`repoB` can then (force) push its changes to common.

And then next time `repoB` pulls from `common` it will get the updates and everybody is in sync.

```
                                   [common/master]
repoA  A - B - C - D - E - F1 - G1 [master]

                                   [common/master]
repoB  A - B - C - D - E - F1 - G1 [master]

common A - B - C - D - E - F1 - G1 [master]
```

`common` can be on any number of services which will provide you with a Git repository. Or it could be on computer B since you can log into it.